# How to Display Small Grab Handle for Hidden UITableView on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an iPad application with a SplitViewController. I am hiding the left hand navigation panel (UITableView).  It can be viewed by swiping in from the left of the screen.  I would like to display a little "grab tab" on the left when it is hidden to give the user a visual indication that there is something there that they can view.  I am just not sure how to go about this.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1

Well, then you will have to put create a view in which your rootViewController(leftView) will reside along with a custom Button with the handle image and you can remove or hide the customButton when your root view is visible and show when your root view is not visible.
Also, you will have to give this view(customButton + leftview) as argument to your splitview during allocation.

Solution 2

You can simply add a customButton to the splitview at the left side and bring it to the front by using [parentview bringSubviewToFront:subview] when rootview is not visible and remove it when it is clicked or swiped according to your functionality.

Hope This Helps You.